# How do files/attachments appear within the JSON output of the Microsoft Graph API 'Get Incident' HTTP call?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps

I'm currently working on an Azure Logic App, and wanted to know how files/attachments appear within the JSON output of the graph api 'get incident' call. All of my test outputs so far have not contained any attachments within the emails, and I need to know how they actually appear in the JSON so as to properly process them. This is one of the outputs I have gotten (information redacted)

```
{
    "body": {
        "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#security/incidents(alerts())/$entity",
        "id": "REDACTED_INCIDENT_ID",
        "tenantId": "REDACTED_TENANT_ID",
        "status": "active",
        "incidentWebUrl": "https://security.microsoft.com/incidents/REDACTED_INCIDENT_ID?tid=REDACTED_TENANT_ID",
        "redirectIncidentId": null,
        "displayName": "Email reported by user as malware or phish involving one user",
        "createdDateTime": "2023-07-XXTXX:XX:XX.Z",
        "lastUpdateDateTime": "2023-07-XXTXX:XX:XX.Z",
        "assignedTo": "REDACTED_TEAM",
        "classification": "unknown",
        "determination": "unknown",
        "severity": "low",
        "customTags": [],
        "comments": [],
        "alerts": [
            {
                "id": "REDACTED_ALERT_ID",
                "providerAlertId": "REDACTED_PROVIDER_ALERT_ID",
                "incidentId": "REDACTED_INCIDENT_ID",
                "status": "resolved",
                "severity": "low",
                "classification": "falsePositive",
                "determination": null,
                "serviceSource": "microsoftDefenderForOffice365",
                "detectionSource": "microsoftDefenderForOffice365",
                "detectorId": "REDACTED_DETECTOR_ID",
                "tenantId": "REDACTED_TENANT_ID",
                "title": "Email reported by user as malware or phish",
                "description": "This alert is triggered when any email message is reported as malware or phish by users -V1.0.0.3",
                "recommendedActions": "",
                "category": "InitialAccess",
                "assignedTo": "C3 Automated Triage Engine",
                "alertWebUrl": "https://security.microsoft.com/alerts/REDACTED_ALERT_ID?tid=REDACTED_TENANT_ID",
                "incidentWebUrl": "https://security.microsoft.com/incidents/REDACTED_INCIDENT_ID?tid=REDACTED_TENANT_ID",
                "actorDisplayName": null,
                "threatDisplayName": null,
                "threatFamilyName": null,
                "mitreTechniques": [
                    "TECHNIQUE"
                ],
                "createdDateTime": "2023-07-XXTXX:XX:XX.Z",
                "lastUpdateDateTime": "2023-07-XXTXX:XX:XX.Z",
                "resolvedDateTime": "2023-07-XXTXX:XX:XX.Z",
                "firstActivityDateTime": "2023-07-XXTXX:XX:XX.Z",
                "lastActivityDateTime": "2023-07-XXTXX:XX:XX.Z",
                "comments": [],
                "evidence": [
                    {
                        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.security.mailboxEvidence",
                        "createdDateTime": "2023-07-XXTXX:XX:XX.Z",
                        "verdict": "unknown",
                        "remediationStatus": "none",
                        "remediationStatusDetails": null,
                        "roles": [],
                        "detailedRoles": [],
                        "tags": [],
                        "primaryAddress": "REDACTED_EMAIL@DOMAIN.COM",
                        "displayName": "REDACTED_NAME",
                        "userAccount": {
                            "accountName": "REDACTED_USERNAME",
                            "domainName": null,
                            "userSid": "REDACTED_USER_SID",
                            "azureAdUserId": "REDACTED_AZURE_AD_USER_ID",
                            "userPrincipalName": "REDACTED_EMAIL@DOMAIN.COM",
                            "displayName": null
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.security.analyzedMessageEvidence",
                        "createdDateTime": "2023-07-XXTXX:XX:XX.Z",
                        "verdict": "unknown",
                        "remediationStatus": "none",
                        "remediationStatusDetails": null,
                        "roles": [],
                        "detailedRoles": [],
                        "tags": [],
                        "networkMessageId": "REDACTED_NETWORK_MESSAGE_ID",
                        "internetMessageId": "REDACTED_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID",
                        "subject": "REDACTED_EMAIL_SUBJECT",
                        "language": "en",
                        "senderIp": null,
                        "recipientEmailAddress": "REDACTED_EMAIL@DOMAIN.COM",
                        "antiSpamDirection": null,
                        "deliveryAction": "delivered",
                        "deliveryLocation": "inbox",
                        "urn": "urn:MailEntity:REDACTED_URN",
                        "threats": [
                            "Phish",
                            "HighConfPhish"
                        ],
                        "threatDetectionMethods": [
                            "MLModel"
                        ],
                        "urls": [
                            "REDACTED_URL_1",
                            "REDACTED_URL_2",
                            "REDACTED_URL_3",
                            "REDACTED_URL_4",
                            "REDACTED_URL_5"
                        ],
                        "urlCount": 5,
                        "attachmentsCount": 0,
                        "receivedDateTime": "2023-06-XXTXX:XX:XX.Z",
                        "p1Sender": {
                            "emailAddress": "REDACTED_SENDER_EMAIL@DOMAIN.COM",
                            "displayName": null,
                            "domainName": "REDACTED_DOMAIN"
                        },
                        "p2Sender": {
                            "emailAddress": "REDACTED_SENDER_EMAIL@DOMAIN.COM",
                            "displayName": "REDACTED_SENDER_NAME",
                            "domainName": "REDACTED_DOMAIN"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

as you can see, this one has no attachments (attachmentsCount: 0) but as I said I need to know how they actually appear. My initial assumption was that they appear in an array similar to the URLs, but I have to be sure (especially since I do not know if they appear as their hashes or something else).

I've tried looking online for any information regarding what the HTTP call output with attachments looks like, with no luck. Microsoft documentation doesn't mention it, and I don't have access to an email/incident with attachments that I could test.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used these APIs before but looking at the response and documentation, I believe you could use the `networkMessageId` property from the incident response and call the [`List Attachments API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/message-list-attachments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to fetch the attachments for the email.

Comment: Oooh ok, that helps quite a bit, that does help me get the attachments and see how they are formatted! The only issue that's left, however, is that I need to run these attachments through VirusTotal, which needs the hash (eg. sha256, md5) of the attachment, which I'm still unsure of how to get using the information provided within the output of the 'Get Attachment' HTTP call

Comment: I don't see a hash in any of the objects unfortunately. Also, I believe once the email comes into Office 365, it will [scan](https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/anti-malware-protection-about?view=o365-worldwide) by the service already. But if you still need to scan it, you would have decode the base64 encoded bytes and hash it yourself looks like.